# Better Protection for Login Data on Firefox for Android?

Tags: security, firefox-for-android

Across the Desktop, Android and iOS versions of Google Chrome and Android, Firefox for Android is the only browser that allows viewing the list of saved passwords even when a master password is set. Specifically, the master password is requested when first starting the browser, but once the browser is in use, it will not be requested again.

Is there a way to get a behavior that is more in line with Chrome / Firefox on other platforms?